# dequeReusableCell is causing new cells to use old styling?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a `tableView` that is set up something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentCell

    let row = indexPath.row
    let cellComment = Comments[row]

    // Remove serperator
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None

    // Set comment content
    cell.commentText.text = Comments[row].content

    // Set level indicator
    var width = CGFloat(Comments[row].level * 5)
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.levelIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: width)
    cell.levelIndicator.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

    return cell
}
```

Comments is an array of Comment structs and setting the `commentText` `TextView` as the `Comment[row].content` works as planned.

My issue appears with the level indicator section of the cell. I am adjusting a view on the left of the cell that expands based on how far down the comment tree a certain comment is.

When the comments are first loaded things look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9YJJ.png)

As you can see the orange view on the left increases correctly and everything looks great. As soon as you scroll down however things start to [fall apart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEfIU.png)

From what I understand from my research online is the table is reusing cells in order to improve performance. These reused cells change the text attributes just fine however they retain the width of the level indicator. Once you start scrolling up and down the cells become a complete mess.

I am unsure how to clear the previous width when the cell is being reused. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a new width constraint every time the cell is prepared.

```
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.levelIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: width)
cell.levelIndicator.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
```

Either remove the old one before adding a new one, or create it once in IB, set an outlet for it and modify its `constant` property by replacing the code above with this one:

```
var width = CGFloat(Comments[row].level * 5)
widthConstraint.constant = width
```

assuming that the name of your outlet is `widthConstraint`.

Comment: Perfect! I added an IBOutlet for the width constraint in the cell's swift file then changed the code like you said just adding "cell." before the widthConstraint. I didn't even know you could make an IBOutlet for constraints, thanks for the advice. It makes sense why just adding constraint after constraint was causing errors.